# how to include extension files of egmap in yii

Tags: php, yii

i want to include and use egmap extension i have created a directory with the name extensions and i have uploaded egmap files .

path is like this  .yiiproject/protected/extensions/egmap/allfiles
but i am getting error no file or stream availible. failed to open file on this line of code

```
Yii::import('ext.egmaps.*');
```

please guide me how to do this

Answer (score 4):

If you download the latest EGMap extension. The zip file has a folder "EGMap" containing all extension related files. Place this folder under `protected/extensions/` folder.

In your view file you could do,

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.EGMap.*');
```

Using the exact case worked for me :-)

Answer (score 3):

you have a typo mistake

```
Yii::import('ext.egmaps.*');
```

should be

```
Yii::import('ext.egmap.*');
```

Comment: sorry. i type it wrong it. now i used the correct name. still i am not able to display map. it is just showing blank page.

Answer (score 1):

i think you would have got your answer by now. Sharing for those who face issues with this in future.

Download EGMap.v.*.*.zip to your machine and unzip it.
Copy all the files inside EGMap folder to

your_project\protected\extensions\

And in the code use

```
Yii::import('ext.egmap.*');
```

to import the functionality